# How to convert and merge a list of webm files into a single large mp4 file with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, mediarecorder, webm, web-mediarecorder

I am using MediaRecorder in the browser to get a chunk of webm file each 5 seconds, so it would end up with a list of webm files stored in AWS S3.

And then, I am currently trying to convert them into one single MP4 file within my Node.js application with the help of ffmpeg. My code looks like this:

```js
async function convertAndMergeWebmStreams(webmStreams, outputFilePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const command = ffmpeg();
    
        // Create a PassThrough stream to combine multiple readable streams
        const combinedStream = new PassThrough();
        
        // Pipe each webmStream into the combinedStream
        webmStreams.forEach(webmStream => {
            webmStream.pipe(combinedStream, { end: false });
        });

        // Set the combinedStream as the input for ffmpeg
        command.input(combinedStream);
    
        // Set input options
        command.inputOptions('-f webm');
    
        // Set output options
        command.outputOptions([
            '-c:v copy',
            '-c:a aac',
        ]);
    
        // Set the output format
        command.toFormat('mp4');
    
        // Set the output file path
        command.output(outputFilePath);
    
        // Event handling
        command
            .on('start', commandLine => {
                console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
            })
            .on('codecData', data => {
                console.log('Input is ' + data.audio + ' audio ' +
                'with ' + data.video + ' video');
            })
            .on('progress', progress => {
                console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done');
            })
            .on('stderr', stderrLine => {
                console.log('Stderr output: ' + stderrLine);
            })
            .on('error', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                console.error('Error converting and merging streams:', err);
                console.error('ffmpeg stdout:', stdout);
                console.error('ffmpeg stderr:', stderr);
                reject(err);
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log('Conversion and merging finished successfully.');
                resolve();
            });
    
        // Run the command
        command.run();
    });
}
```

And now ffmpeg says that:

```
[matroska,webm @ 0x3712a6f0] EBML header parsing failed
[in#0 @ 0x3712a5f0] Error opening input: Invalid data found when processing input
Error opening input file pipe:0.
Error opening input files: Invalid data found when processing input

convertAndMergeWebmStreams error:  Error: ffmpeg exited with code 183: Error opening input file pipe:0.
Error opening input files: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Based on [this link](https://github.com/node-ebml/node-ebml/issues/110), it seems it is a known issue that it does not have a valid EBML header with MediaRecorder from browsers. Is there another way to merge them and get one single MP4 file?

Comment: You can use multipart upload in S3 and upload each of these 5s chunks. Then finally S3 would stitch up all those chucks and give you the full webm file. Then you can use a lambda to convert it to mp4. Look up multipart uploads in s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is because my webms are chunks of a larger file, which makes all files except the first one don't have a valid header. So what I need to do is to merge them in the correct order.